# Added latency of using BatchWriteItem instead of PutItem for a single item in DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an app that, on a regular basis, inserts a single item per request into DynamoDb. Every now and then though, we could expect to see multiple items inserted, in which case I would like to utilize the `BatchWriteItem` action instead of `PutItem`.

What I am wondering is, if I use `BatchWriteItem` for all requests, will that result in an increase in latency as opposed to using `PutItem` for the single/few item(s) case?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do a simple conditional check within your code?

Comment: No, that is definitely an option. But then I started wondering where I should place the limit, is it a single item or ten, etc. And that led me to the question of whether it made any difference, BatchWriteItem or PutItem. I would prefer a single command, but mostly due to code clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical request for a `BatchWriteItem` is *by a very, very small amount* larger than a single `PutItem` or `DeleteItem` request.

This may then result in a *very, very small* increased latency measurement as more data needs to be transported over the network, but I would say that this would be extremely negligible.

That said, while using `BatchWriteItem` for every request will have no real impact on your application, I would expect the right SDK methods/API calls are made for the right situation when reviewing code.

I would advise to, at the very least, add a conditional check and use `PutItem` for single items. If the count of items are more than 2, you can use `BatchWriteItem`.